# install software remotely from tomcat

Tags: windows, tomcat7

I am using tomcat7, jsf2, spring and other frameworks. I am new in this.

I have a question about remote installation or sending a command line to a remote computer.

I have this situation:

1. I have Tomcat server (windows), which registers tasks.
2. After registration, the server must send any command to the remote station (windows) to start simple file for that task.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if someone is interesting in this, I used this tools (for intranet):

1. Spring Quartz (executes jobs)
2. xcmd (sending this command with runtime)